# Pressing space bar in Word 2010 types '[' character

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

In Microsoft Word 2010, when I press the space bar, `[` is typed. How can I change it back? My keyboard layout is US-English.

Comment: What did you try? What is your keyboard layout?

Comment: I am using US-English.

Comment: Go to `file - options - proofing - autocorrect options` and make sure there's not a new rule there replacing space with a character

Comment: Sounds very odd—certainly possible, due to keyboard settings or “autocorrection,” but it’s more like April 1st stuff. Does this happen all the time, or in specific contexts only? Which contexts?

Comment: well If i press one time then it is shown. But if long press spaceBar then on first letter'[' is seen, then after that it is all fine. Strange one i have never deal with that one.

Comment: Does it do this on a new unformatted non-template document?

Comment: yes that happen in that too. i did like suggested by  @Raystafarian. but that too didnt work. now i think i will reinstall that.